# Click event for ellipse in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, graphics, ellipse

I am creating an **ellipse** in a picture box in vb.net, and i want that if ever i click this ellipse it will open another form. The picture box contains an image of a map and i just simply put ellipses on the buildings found in the map, and i guess you get the idea that it will show me the information about that building...

Note: if you have an easier way of **creating an interactive map** in vb.net where information and images about the map are stored in a mysql database..

Comment: How are you creating the ellipse and which technology are you using Winforms, Wpf or ?

Comment: You could check if the given point falls inside the ellipse using the area formula: `mouse_x * mouse_y <= A * B` [assuming a center of (0, 0)], where A and B are the ellipse's radii. [Area of an Ellipse](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10006.3.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample application demonstrating the use of the area to calculate if a point falls inside an ellipse:

NOTE: Create a new WinForms application and paste the code inside the `Form1.vb`:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ellipse_center As Point

    Private A As Integer = 140
    Private B As Integer = 90

    Private isInsideEllipse As Boolean

    Private canvasRect As Rectangle

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)

        Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        isInsideEllipse = (e.Location.X - ellipse_center.X) ^ 2 / (A / 2) ^ 2 + (e.Location.Y - ellipse_center.Y) ^ 2 / (B / 2) ^ 2 <= 1
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics

        Using p As New Pen(If(isInsideEllipse, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Red), 2)
            g.DrawEllipse(p, ellipse_center.X - A \ 2, ellipse_center.Y - B \ 2, A, B)
        End Using

        g.DrawString("Pointer is" + If(isInsideEllipse, " ", " not ") + "inside the ellipse", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 5)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        canvasRect = Me.DisplayRectangle
        canvasRect.Inflate(-1, -1)

        ellipse_center = New Point(canvasRect.Width / 2, canvasRect.Height / 2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

By the way, I found the correct formula here: [Check if a point is within an ellipse @ Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse)

Comment: tnx a lot... your a life saver... time to connect this click button to mysql via navicat.....

Comment: Glad to be of help @ReysterRautCarba